# How do I access filters through external URL and highlight only active filter class in the menu?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

My Isotope gallery, which you can see [here](https://thedivtagguy.com) uses the code below to update the URL hashes in the address bar depending on which class is selected. If you select class `Mishmash`, you will see `https://thedivtagguy.com/#filter=.mishmash`  in the address bar. This part works well but if you try going to this [Mishmash](https://thedivtagguy.com/#filter=.mishmash) category url I showed you above, it only highlights the filter class and doesn't actually sort the grid.

**EDIT:** This seems to be working off and on.

Why is this not working, the code seems to be valid?

```
<script>
(function($) {
    

function getHashFilter() {
  var hash = location.hash;
  // get filter=filterName
  var matches = location.hash.match( /filter=([^&]+)/i );
  var hashFilter = matches && matches[1];
  return hashFilter && decodeURIComponent( hashFilter );
}
$( function() {

  var $grid = $('.isotope');

  // bind filter button click
  var $filters = $('#filters').on( 'click', 'li', function() {
    var filterAttr = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    // set filter in hash
    location.hash = 'filter=' + encodeURIComponent( filterAttr );
  });

  var isIsotopeInit = false;

  function onHashchange() {
    var hashFilter = getHashFilter();
    if ( !hashFilter && isIsotopeInit ) {
      return;
    }
    isIsotopeInit = true;
    console.log(hashFilter);
    // filter isotope
    $grid.isotope({
      // itemSelector: '.selector.col-md-6.col-lg-4',
      filter: hashFilter
    });
    // set selected class on button
    if ( hashFilter ) {
      $filters.find('.active').removeClass('active');
      console.log($filters.find('.active'));
      $filters.find('[data-filter="' + hashFilter + '"]').addClass('active');
    }
  }

  $(window).on( 'hashchange', onHashchange );

  // trigger event handler to init Isotope
  onHashchange();
});
    
})( jQuery );
```

Secondly, I've tried adding these links to my main menu (so that the grid is navigable from the top and if the user is on other pages, it would redirect to home and just filter the grid) and I've entered the full URLs for each category as the links, so the main menu has item `Mishmash` which has the link `https://thedivtagguy.com/#filter=.mishmash`. As you can see in the image below, for some reason **all** of the links are active but it's useless navigating using them; only the URL in the address bar changes without actually filtering. Which part of the code is causing this to happen and how do I make the other links inactive?

**UPDATE:** Video clip of the problem available [here](https://gofile.io/d/5aJ4oA)

[image]

Comment: both of them working fine in chrome

Comment: @ash Have you tried switching classes using the main menu at the top? I'm using Chrome too but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: check out my answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main issues in your code:

1. You are `.isotope` for container selection, but you do not have any container with class `isotope` instead change your code to `var $grid = $('.masonry');`
2. You have some class and ids set for your secondary navigation menu, use same classes for your main navigation menu as well, if you want to have active filter link highlighted. Which means adding:

   2.1 `data-filter` attribute to `li` elements

   2.2  change `var $filters = $('#filters')` to `var $filters = $('#filters, #menu-portfolio-1')`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The first part has worked like a charm, I don't know why I didn't do it sooner. I've been trying to dynamically ad the class in with jQuery instead of doing it simple like this! The second part still does not work, however. [Here is a screenshot of the code for the secondary navigation](https://ibb.co/hR5Bq6W), I'm adding in the class `m-filters` to my menu items but no luck. Should it be `m-filters`, `filters` or `data-filters`?

Comment: @namnban check updated answer. Also you have wrong style `.m-nav-menu--horizontal ul.menu li.menu-item.current_page_item > a` in you page.

Comment: Thank you Dipen. Adding the `data-filter` attribute to the `li` elements in Wordpress is another battle altogether which I will not trouble you with. I'll try what you have suggest. Thanks again! I will award your bounty as soon as the timer lets me.

Answer (score 0):

for showing active category and sorted items... you have to assign your `onHashchange()` inside window onload function.

```
window.onload = function() {
   onHashchange()
};
```

more info [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just to make sure, [this](https://pastebin.com/sRaMCAKt) is what I'm putting before the closing `<head>` tag. The issue still isn't resolved, as you can see in this video clip: https://gofile.io/d/5aJ4oA

Comment: actually there is a SyntaxError, I update my answer reupdate your code